# Count number of pairs for unique values in a table

Tags: sql

I have two columns in a table - A and B such as

```
A           B

x---------  I
y---------  I
z---------  III
n---------  IV
m---------  IV
q----------IV
```

How do I count number of values in A that correspond to unique value in B
The answer should look like

```
**Value**  **Count**
I ------------2
III-----------1
IV------------3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What code have you tried so far? Please edit your answer to include this. Otherwise, your questions reads like you are asking us to code for you and SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, this is a basic [count](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) and [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement (that should work with probably any DBMS).

```
SELECT B, COUNT(A)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY B
```